# Rectangle and button are skewed even they have same frame in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, button, coordinates

[image]I'm working on Swift 5 with Xcode 11.7 in a project. In here, I have a button and draw a rectangle around it. Everything is fine until I run it in iPhone 11 (11 pro, 11 pro max) simulator. Even I have set x,y of rectangle as same as the button's but they are skewed, other simulator didn't have this situation.

How can I fix this problem. Many thanks.

Question to me if it is not clear enough for you.

Here is my code to make a rectangle and make it around the button.

```
let rect = CGRect(x: btnSignIn2.frame.origin.x - 10, y: btnSignIn2.frame.origin.y + btnSignIn2.layer.bounds.height + 10, width: btnSignIn2.layer.bounds.width + 20, height: btnSignIn2.layer.bounds.height + 20)
let spotlight1 = AwesomeSpotlight(withRect: rect,
            shape: .roundRectangle,
            text: "message_please_login".localized(),
            labelPosition: CGRect(x: 0, y: rect.maxY - btnSignIn2.layer.bounds.height + 25, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100),
            isAllowPassTouchesThroughSpotlight: true)
```

The screenshot I put down here is the problem I have. The left side is iPhone11, and the other side is one of other simulator.

Comment: can u provide a screenshot plz

Comment: excuse me, you want screenshot of codes or the results ?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of result.

Comment: *"I have a button and draw a rectangle around it"* ... How are you doing that? Show your code. Are you using auto-layout / constraints? Or explicit x/y/width/height frames? Is this laid-out in IB / Storyboard? or via code?

Comment: I just show my code. I did use auto-layout, it worked fine in all simulators that Xcode supports, except iPhone 11/11pro/11pro max.

Comment: One more thing is, I tried few times and realized that y of rectangle was placed higher than button's when I set them to the same value. It doesn't happen on other simulators, only on iPhone 11s.

Comment: I've fixed it, by checking device is running are iPhone 11s or not, and changing "y coordinate". This is the only way I can handle it now. Thanks for your attention.